# How is the difference between database and a 2D matrix?

Tags: vb.net, string

I am creating a Visual basic program which will handle 100k strings. Yes! "100K". Each string is a sentence long. I need to make sure a search function in my program is reasonably fast. The search function returns all strings in the memory that contain a search keyword.

I am new to VB. My question is whether I should use database (No experience)   or I should use 2D string array? What would be advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Comment: Side note: Your numbers are strange: "Each string is a sentence long" is not very precise; "reasonably fast" is not good enough to say if you achieved it or not: i.e. something like 10 searches/second would be better goal.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for your suggestion. "Each string is a sentence long" because each string is really an English sentence. "Reasonably fast" because I really have no experience and open to any suggestion. I don't want to make a statement that does not match with the real world expectation, like "I hope that I can run 500 mile per hour after a week of training".

Answer (score 1):

If you need many searches just build map of all encountered words to list of sentences (i.e. `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` where `int` is index of a sentence).

You may be able to compress sentence representation by representing it as list of words (may use String.Intern, to avoid duplicate copies of the same word in memory) if you are too worried about memory usage.

Comment: How many seconds will a regular 4-core computer needs to search in a 100MB Dictionary? Could you please give me a range? Like "less than 5sec", "in between 10-15 sec"

Comment: @Marco, Search in dictionary is O(1)... So time to get an item does not depend on the size. (Check out MSDN article on [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)).

Comment: Search in a hash table is driven by collision resolution, typical implementations have worst case O(n).  The linked doc is wise enough not to discuss this.